# numpy array reshape astype too slow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

for a 640x480x3 image read in from a webcam, the bottleneck of preparing it for TensorFlow is this reshape command:

```
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):

    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape((im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
```

Why does this take so very long, and is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: You're sure `image.getdata()` isn't the problem? Did you use a profiler here, or just a couple of prints? `reshape` does nothing with your data (it's just metadata, it doesn't shuffle memory around). A cast to `np.uint8` should also be fast.

Comment: I think you are right that the getdata() command is the slow part

Answer (score 0):

I was able to cut the operation with

```
import time
import picamera
import numpy as np

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (320, 240)
    camera.framerate = 24
    time.sleep(2)
    output = np.empty((240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(output, 'rgb')
```

Comment: It is unclear how this fixed the problem, it seems quite different from your question. If your problem is fixed, I think you should delete your question.